# jQuery SlideDown Submenu Top Margin

Tags: jquery, html, css, joomla3.0

I have the following code for slide down menu:

```
jQuery(window).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.menu>li').hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('ul').first().stop(true,true).slideDown(400);
    }, 
    function(){
        jQuery(this).find('ul').first().stop(true,true).slideUp();
    });

    jQuery('.menu>li>ul>li').hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('ul').first().stop(true,true).slideDown(400);
    }, 
    function(){
        jQuery(this).find('ul').first().stop(true,true).slideUp();
    });
});
```

It works swimmingly, except when .menu ul ul is displayed, it slides down one level down from its parent item, so one cannot hover over it. I fixed that using a negative margin-top for .menu ul ul, but that way the slideDown function looks like it is sliding from mid-way to top and bottom, rather than from top to down. Any suggestions on how to put a permanent fix on this either through jQuery or CSS?

Here's the CSS file:

```
.menu {
         padding:0;
         margin: 0;
}

.menu ul{
         list-style: none;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;       
}

.menu li{ /*these will be main menu items*/
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  line-height: 37px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li ul { /*first drop-down*/
 left: -999em;
 position: absolute;
 width: 186px;
 z-index: 500;
 background: #666666;
 display: none;
}

.menu li:hover ul {
  left: auto;
}

.menu li ul ul {
 margin-left: 186px; 
 display: none;
}

.menu li ul li {
  text-align: left;
  width: 186px;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.menu li.active a {
  background: #454545;
}

.menu a:hover{
 color: #FBF4B6;
 background: #333;
}

.menu li ul li a {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-bottom:2px;
  padding-top:2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

.menu li.active ul li a:hover {
  background: #333;
}
```

Comment: Hey George, Can you please add an example to jsFiddle? I dont whats your HTML.

Comment: I am not yet sure on what is wrong.  Somehow submenu is getting a margin of 40px.  A hacky way is to add "margin-top: -40px" to the submenu ul, so that the submenu moves up. I will let you know if I find a better solution.

Comment: Yes, I already knew I could do that, but theres a problem when I do that - the submenu slides both up and down to get to the top margin, instead of just sliding down from the top. In the regular CSS menu that was how it was fixed, but it does not work very well with the jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found how to solve this here: http://jsfiddle.net/297t6/

```
.menu
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.menu > li
{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
.menu a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    background:red;
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
}
.menu > li ul
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:150px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    z-index: 999;
}
.menu > li ul ul
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:150px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    left:150px;
    top:0;
    z-index: 999;
}
.menu > li ul li
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
}
```

Copied the CSS and Javascript (which is much cleaner than what I had), changed class names an voilla - it works.